# Changing ImageView Based on Selection In A CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I currently have a `CollectionView` with 1 reusable cell where it's filled up with a `ImageView`. This cell is used 10 times to show 10 different animals (I provide the pics for the cell). I also have a label above this collection view. Every time a user presses on a cell, the label will change to "*Name of the animal* selected". **What I now want is for the cell image to get darker when it's selected and go back to normal when it's not selected.** As of now I know how to change the image of the cell to a darker one by manually switching it with a darker one, but I do not know how to change it back to normal as I pick on another one. **How do I implement this?** I have copied my code at the bottom:

```
//cell configuration
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        //define the cell
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AnimalSelectionCell

        //animals is name of array of different types of animals
        cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: animals[indexPath.row])
        cell.animalImage.restorationIdentifier = animals[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    //choosing an animal
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
            let currentCell = collectionview.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AnimalSelectionCell
            let animal = currentCell.animalImage.restorationIdentifier! //gets what type of animal selected
            selectionLabel.text = "\(animal) selected" //changes label
            currentCell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: animal + "Selected") //changes to darker animal image                 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `var` called `selectedIndexpath` and in your `didSelectItemAt` method change by the selected indexpath, if the selectedIndexPath is the same you should make selectedIndexpath to nil and in your `cellForItemAt` method you only need to check if the current indexPath is equal to your selectedIndexpath property

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? //declare this

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        //define the cell
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AnimalSelectionCell

        //animals is name of array of different types of animals
        cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: animals[indexPath.row])
        if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath){
            //if indexpath is selected use your darker image
            cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: animal + "Selected")
        }
        cell.animalImage.restorationIdentifier = animals[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    //choosing an animal
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
            let currentCell = collectionview.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AnimalSelectionCell
            let animal = currentCell.animalImage.restorationIdentifier! //gets what type of animal selected
            selectionLabel.text = "\(animal) selected" //changes label
            var prevSelectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
            if(selectedIndexPath != nil){
                 if(selectedIndexPath == indexPath){
                     selectedIndexPath = nil
                 }else{
                     prevSelectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: selectedIndexPath.row, section: selectedIndexPath.section)
                     selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                 }
            }else{
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }

            if(prevSelectedIndexPath != nil){
                 collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath,prevSelectedIndexPath])
            }else{
                 collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            }
        }

func clearSelection(){
    if(selectedIndexPath != nil){
         let prevSelectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: selectedIndexPath.row, section: selectedIndexPath.section)
         selectedIndexPath = nil
         self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [prevSelectedIndexPath])
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the selected animal the darker image, but whenever I select another animal, the animal I previously selected image is still darkened. How do I fix this?

Comment: Also I have a clear button and when I press it the label changes to "no animals selected". Which part of this code should I use in the IBAction code so when I press the clear button all of the images go back to normal?

Comment: @fphelp check my answer i had added a clearSelection function with your needed implementation for that last requeriment

Comment: @fphelp I am glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you must subclass UICollectionViewCell and override the `isSelected` property:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected {
        willSet(bool) {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray // or whatever
        }
    }
}
```